# Asymmetric DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc

### Context

I want to supply power to three devices with voltages 3V, 9V and 12V. Each of them may need up to 5A current. They work independently, e.g. device 3V may be turned on while device 12V is off etc.

If I had at hand 3V and 9V power supplies and chained them together I could also use it as 12V power supply. So I would have 3 wires: -3V, 0, +9V.

### Question 1

Are there any objectives reasons not to do it?

### Question 2

Is design with 4 wires (0, +3V, +9V, +12V) any better/more robust?

### Question 3

Are there any dedicated designs for such an asymmetric (with 3 wires) power supply?

Comment: I bet your 12 V device is not designed to be powered from +9 V and -3 V.  That would mean connecting the GND of the 12 V device to -3 V, which I don't think is recommended.

Comment: If the supplies are not of the isolated type they will short out since an unisolated supply has output and input ground connected, and then all input  grounds are connected since they all plug into the same wall. If you try to then connect a positive output to another supply's ground output, you are connecting it's positive output to its own ground output = short.

Comment: And the three devices cannot be connected to each other in any way (no signal wires running  between them either.).

Comment: I'd source 3 power supplies and not monkey around with swapping wires.   If a single supply is a must, you can get a benchtop DC supply that can give you 5A at any voltage you want for not alot of money  $$$$  I wouldn't go putting 3 mis-matched power supplies in series.   Funny things can happen....

Comment: @steveSh by itself, how would that device know the difference between -3 to 9v and 0 to 12v?

Comment: @Passerby - It might not "know", or care, if it is totally isolated (floating) from the rest of its environment.  But as soon as you connect something else to it like a serial interface cable (that is not galvanically isolated), the driving device now sees -3V where it might have been expecting GND.

Comment: It does depend on the devices and how they interact : level translation between them (and ensuring it all works with all combinations of powered/unpowered) would probably be much more complicated than the simple approach with a common 0V.

Comment: @Hans - If you do what you suggested - "If I had at hand 3V and 9V power supplies and chained them together I could also use it as 12V power supply. So I would have 3 wires: -3V, 0, +9V.", the 3V and 9V power supplies would have to be able to handle 10 amps of current.